# NSArrayController why this doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to write a routine that imports from a tab-delimited file hundreds of customers records into a NSArrayController.

This is my initial code:

```
NSString *stringFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[fileURL path]
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *paragraphsArray = [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
NSMutableDictionary *destDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

int i;
for (i = 0; i <= [paragraphsArray count]-1; i++) {
    NSString *currentParagraph = [paragraphsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([currentParagraph length ] > 4) {
        NSArray *elementsArray = [currentParagraph componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
        if ([elementsArray count] > 0) {
            currentSerial++;
            [destDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentSerial]
                         forKey:@"idSerial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:1]
                         forKey:@"destRazaoSocial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:2]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouro"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:3]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouroNro"];
            /// repeat this for every field...
            //Add the record:
            [destArrayController addObject:destDict];
        }
    }
}
```

This code causes the records to be inserted wrongly, if I have 4 records in an example, the four records inserted will have the same content as the last record.

But if I change the code to this, allocing destDict and trashing it on every loop, it works:

```
NSString *stringFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[fileURL path]
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *paragraphsArray = [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= [paragraphsArray count]-1; i++) {
    NSString *currentParagraph = [paragraphsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([currentParagraph length ] > 4) {
        NSArray *elementsArray = [currentParagraph componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
        if ([elementsArray count] > 0) {
            NSMutableDictionary *destDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            currentSerial++;
            [destDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentSerial]
                         forKey:@"idSerial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:1]
                         forKey:@"destRazaoSocial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:2]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouro"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:3]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouroNro"];
            /// repeat this for every field...
            //Add the record:
            [destArrayController addObject:destDict];
            [destDict release];
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but it doesn't look elegant to me.
Would you be so kind to show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing it the second way you posted. The other way to do it (which may or may not be better) is to do it the first way, but add [destDict copy] instead of destDict to your array.

Another point about your for loop -- if you don't need to use the index, which you don't in your code, you should be using fast enumeration. It's faster and easier to write. So, this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= [paragraphsArray count]-1; i++) {
    NSString *currentParagraph = [paragraphsArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

can be done like this (called a for-in loop):

```
for (NSString *currentParagraph in paragraphArray){
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first code does not work is that you are creating the `NSMutableDictionary` outside of the loop, changing its contents, and then adding it multiple times to an array.

When you add an object to an array, it doesn't create an actual copy of the object, but instead, the array simply sends that object a `retain` message. So in your first code segment, because you created the `destDict` instance outside of the loop, you end up adding the same `destDict` instance to the array multiple times. Because it's the same instance, the dictionary will effectively have the contents from the changes you made on the very last loop.

You can use the code like in your second example, but instead of creating the `destDict` using `alloc/init`, just create an auto-released instance using `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`. Then there's no need to add the `[destDict release];` line after adding it to the array controller. (Not a big deal, but anyway)...

```
NSString *stringFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[fileURL path]
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *paragraphsArray = [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= [paragraphsArray count]-1; i++) {
    NSString *currentParagraph = [paragraphsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([currentParagraph length ] > 4) {
        NSArray *elementsArray = [currentParagraph componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
        if ([elementsArray count] > 0) {

            NSMutableDictionary *destDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

            currentSerial++;
            [destDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentSerial]
                         forKey:@"idSerial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:1]
                         forKey:@"destRazaoSocial"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:2]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouro"];
            [destDict setObject:[elementsArray objectAtIndex:3]
                         forKey:@"destLogradouroNro"];
            /// repeat this for every field...
            //Add the record:
            [destArrayController addObject:destDict];
        }
    }
}
```